# ¿Cómo tomar la url de un template y abrir otro template en Django?

Tags: python, django

Estoy armando una pagina web de películas en django, quiero seleccionar una película y mostrar los actores, directores y critica.
El problema que tengo, es que cuando selecciono el botón "Mas Info", no me redirecciona a la pagina que deseo.

Vista:

```
class PeliculasView(View):

    template_name="PeliculasInfo.html"    #selecciono el template   
    form_class = criticaForm              #formas del formulario         
    model = Pelicula                      #modelo que utilizo


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):               
        id =self.kwargs['pk']
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        print(context)
        context['pelicula'] =Pelicula.objects.get(pk = id)
        context['Actores']=Actores.objects.filter(pelicula=id)
        context['Director']=Director.objects.filter(pelicula=id)
        context['criticas']=Critica.objects.filter(pelicula=id)
        context["titulo"] = "PeliculasWeb 2023 | Informacion"
        context['form']=self.form_class
    
        return context
```

URL:

```
urlpatterns = [ 
    path("", views.HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),
    path("info/<int:pk>/", views.PeliculasView.as_view(), name="info"),
]  + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

BOTON EN EL TEMPLATE:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="{% url "info" pk=p.id%}">
  <i class="bi bi-info-square-fill"></i> Mas Info.
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un puntos que debes corregir:

- La clase View de la cual hereda no tiene le metodo `get_context_data`, por ende se debe modificar esa declaracion.
- No estas implementando el metodo http para devolver un template y pasar el objeto de contexto, por ende no se visualiza nada.

La solucion pueden ser la siguiente:

```
class PeliculasView(View):
    template_name = 'PeliculasInfo.html'
    form_class = criticaForm

    def get(self, request, pk):  # Implementa el metodo get, le pasas el pk como parametro que declaras en el path de tu url
        context = {
            'pelicula': Pelicula.objects.get(pk=pk),
            'Actores': Actores.objects.filter(pelicula=pk),
            'Director': Director.objects.filter(pelicula=pk),
            'criticas': Critica.objects.filter(pelicula=pk),
            "titulo": "PeliculasWeb 2023 | Informacion",
            'form': self.form_class
        }

        return render(request, self.template_name, context) # Returnas el método render que mostrara el contenido del template y el diccionario de contexto.
```

Y el boton quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" >
  <a href="{% url 'info' pk=p.id %}"><i class="bi bi-info-square-fill">sda</i> Mas Info.</a>
</button>
```